# JQuery trigger('input') does not fire native JavaScript input event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, addeventlistener

I have a code which needs to trigger the input event manually on an input with a datepicker.

The code looks like:

```
input.on('apply.daterangepicker', function(e) {
    input.trigger('input');
});

input.on('input', function(e) {
    console.log('11111111111111111111');
});

document.getElementById('filter-created-at').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    console.log('22222222222222222222');
});
```

The first jQuery event listener works fine. But the second pure JavaScript does not catch the input event. Don't understand it. How can I catch input from `trigger()` with pure JavaScript `addEventListener()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Element#dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) to trigger an input event.

```js
document.getElementById('filter-created-at').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  console.log('Regular input');
});
$('#filter-created-at').on('input', function(e) {
  console.log('jQuery input');
});
document.getElementById('filter-created-at').dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {
  bubbles: true
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="filter-created-at" />
```

Comment: This is the only way? No simpler and cleaner solution? It should be  simpler.

Comment: @Čamo This isn't a difficult solution to use. I don't believe there is any other way.

Comment: I hope there is something like element.input() like element.submit().

Comment: @Čamo Unfortunately, there is no such method.

Comment: Ok thank you it works. But I dont understand why jquery trigger() does not call dispatchEvent()? I expected that.